# Java: Organizing elements from returned array

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a better way to write this code? I tried a for loop to go through every element, but then it made my JOptionPane display 5 windows. Also, I assigned an int variable to each "getValueX", but still had 5 windows displaying each element. Thanks!

```
int v11, v12, v13, v14, v15;
int v21, v22, v23, v24, v25;

v11 = inputDie1[0].getValue1();
v12 = inputDie1[1].getValue1();
v13 = inputDie1[2].getValue1();
v14 = inputDie1[3].getValue1();
v15 = inputDie1[4].getValue1();

v21 = inputDie2[0].getValue2();
v22 = inputDie2[1].getValue2();
v23 = inputDie2[2].getValue2();
v24 = inputDie2[3].getValue2();
v25 = inputDie2[4].getValue2();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, v11 + "   " + v21 + "\n" + v12 + "   " + v22 + "\n" 
           + v13 + "   " + v23 + "\n" + v14 + "   " + v24 +  "\n" + v15 + "   " + v25);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got 5 dialogs likely because you placed the dialog call in the loop. Consider this approach:

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    message.append(inputDie1[i].getValue1() + "   " + inputDie2[i].getValue2() + "\n");
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message.toString());
```